# Can I change the server name and IP address when I send an e-mail message with mailer?

Tags: php, email

I want to add custom sender ip and custom server name when i send my email using my hosting provider mailer .I use mailer:

[My mail PHP Mail form](http://v31.us/send.php)

I want to show this mail information instead of the original server information.

> Received: from BLU179-W29 ([65.55.111.71]) by
>   blu0-omc2-s1.blu0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);

Comment: You'd like to spam and hide your tracks?

Comment: This `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];` shows IP address. You can't modify those, unless... (ahem) as per above comment.

Comment: No. You cannot control the headers that the hotmail servers are inserting.

Comment: @devva Do you understand why you're receiving hostile responses to your question or are you truly ignorant as to the dangers surrounding email marketing? To the trained eye you're launching an open spam platform and don't seem to care about the ramifications.

Comment: IIRC dewa had like 5 points when I edited the question... he would have negative points now if SO allowed that...

Answer (score 0):

This information is generated by the receiver, and it is not possible to be changed by the sending party (nor is it meant to). I truly doubt you can find a valid reason to do so anyway.

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment and not considered as an "answer".

Comment: @devva Show us your code and your real intentions as per [Mike B's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831328/can-i-change-the-server-name-and-ip-address-when-i-send-an-e-mail-message-with-m#comment27780204_18831328)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: It is an answer -- it cannot be done. The next part (me not believing there is a valid reason for this) is a comment indeed.

Comment: @devva Any which way, I rather not take part in giving answers to potential Spammers/Spoofers. The way the OP worded the question seems obvious.

Comment: @hexblot: it would be clearer if you explicitly stated that it's not possible, rather than just saying it's not meant to be done (which leaves open the possibility that a clever person might find a way to do it).